# Uncheck selected radio button

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to work out how to un-check a radio button if it is clicked/selected for a second time.

So, if I have 4 radio buttons, and button 1 is selected, and the user clicks on button 1 again, it "de-selects" so none of the radio buttons are selected.

I have this code which does not fire when an "already selected" radio button is clicked:

```
this.selectedAgeBreakdown.subscribe((newVal) => {
  Alert("Clicked!";
});
```

Can anyone give me any ideas please?

Comment: How have you implemented the "deselection"?

Comment: no. perhaps this is what I am missing :( - can you give me any tips on where/how I would do that?

Comment: Maybe you need a multiselect instead of radio buttons.

Comment: simple . you can achieve using `click` check here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/27403/ . cheers

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons typically do not support this behavior; there is no way to unselect any one of them. If your page by default has a state of "no selected radios" then that's a special state you normally can't return to once you clicked one. It's not Knockout-specific. See this example:

```css
label:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="opt" /> Option 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="2" name="opt" /> Option 2</label>
```

Note that once you select one of them, you can *not* unselect that one anymore.

With Knockout (or JavaScript in general) you *could* workaround that. If you handle the `click` event you could react to an option that's already checked being clicked.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.opt = ko.observable(null);  
  
  self.tryDeselect = function(viewModel, event) {
    if (event.target.value === self.opt()) { 
      self.opt(null);
      event.target.checked = false; 
    }
    return true; 
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
label:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" value="1" data-bind="click: tryDeselect, checked: opt" /> Option 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="2" data-bind="click: tryDeselect, checked: opt" /> Option 2</label>
<hr>
Debug info: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></pre>
```

From a UX perspective, you could also consider using a list of *checkboxes*:

- Advantage: a user *expects* being able to deselect a checkbox (with a radio button you do *not* expect to have that ability);
- Advantage: no need for handling DOM stuff in your view model, just plain KO bindings that handle "unchecking" the other ones once you check one of them;
- Disadvantage: UX-wise mutually-exclusive checkboxes are not (without some added visual hints) what a user typically expects;
- Disadvantage: might require some more code to get the mutually-exclusive bit going;